# При входе на сетевую папку PowerShell выдает ошибку

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-server-2016

При входе на сетевую папку, PowerShell выдает ошибку что не удается найти путь, хотя через Проводник и Total Commander заходит без проблем.
Зайти пытаюсь на Server 2016 с помощью `cd`

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, это проблема на PS, а команды `CD`. В PS это делается командой `Set-Location`. Или можно использовать обходные пути для CMD, такие как `net use` или `pushd`

Comment: А тоже самое пишет.

Comment: Проверьте: 1) нет ли опечатки в пути 2) не нужно ли экранировать путь из-за спецсимволов

Comment: Проверил на PS v6 (Win 10) - cd прекрасно обрабатывает UNC-пути. Причем как с прямыми, так и с обратными слешами

Comment: @ГерманБорисов на виндовом Posershell `cd` - это псевдоним для `Set-Location`

Comment: В аргументе случайно пробелов нет? А то может просто кавычки забыли.

Comment: Не понятно почему, но сегодня зашел. Хотя коллега сказал, что максимум что делал, добавлял эту папку net use-ом

Comment: может powershell был запущен с привилегиями администратора, Total Commander -, соотвественно, с обвычными?

Comment: а что, доступ с привилегиями администратора может быть ограничен по сравнению с обычным?